# Who can explain me how to use "就"?

Tags: word

It seems 就 is a very frequently used word. I'm just confused about its use. Anyone can help to explain how to use it?

Comment: search web with e.g. "Chinese grammar", "实用现代汉语语发" ISBN 7-100-03210-5, discusses 就 along with 才 in part 14 (pp.247-253) of 常用副词的用法 (frequently used adverbs (213-262)

Comment: Treat it just like "and". In chinese there are lots of "and" and 就 is one of them. 

I got up AND(就) washed my face.

Answer (score 1):

就

1. means emphasize,can translate as "just", for example, "我就是不想去"(I just don't want to go!), used mostly.
2. means under some condition, once, for example ,"我一吃海鲜就想吐"(I will get a sick once I eat seafood.), used frequencely.
3. means relying on or with, for example, "就着菜吃饭"(Eating rice with a dish.)
4. means successful ,like "一蹴而就"(Success at once.), rarely used.

That's all I understood for experience.

Answer (score 0):

"就" is used with a verb or adjective to mean "something will happen in very short time" and is translated as "right now, right away, at once, very soon, be about to, be going to, be doing, etc. ". "就“ also expresses a meaning that one action happens immediately after another.  I just found this content with the explanation of 就 http://www.decodemandarinchinese.com/learn-better/?tag=%E5%B0%B1